# Is there a way to file.create() a file with file type of MISCBINARY aka other binary file with suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Title says it all, has anyone figured out a way to create and save a file with the equivalent of what would be the enum file.type.MISCBINARY via suitescript suitelet N/file module (this does not exist in any documentation)

I have already found that I can upload any file to whatever ns file type I want regardless of file mime or .ext however I would like to not just upload files to the wrong NS enum just to get the job done.

example, I am currently creating .msg files under the type enum file.Type.MESSAGERFC as this is the closest match however if uploaded through drag and drop the type field is MISCBINARY

I have been through all of the documentation and even dug into several of the object properties, I also took a look at the form object of a MISCBINARY file uploaded through the NS drag and drop feature.
I have tried in the type field:
file.Type.MISCBINARY
'MISCBINARY'
'miscbinary'
'otherbinaryfile'

I also tried to set the file.fileType property by file.fileType = 'MISCBINARY' of course this did not work since this property is readOnly but it was worth a shot.